# 7 doubts about the von Neumann algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

> A von Neumann algebra, or $W^*$-algebra, is a $*$-algebra of bounded operators on a Hilbert space that is closed in the weak operator topology and contains the identity operator. It is a special type of $C^*$-algebra.

I want to ask some things

1. Why a $W^*$-algebra is *closed* in the weak operator topology?
2. Why a $W^*$-algebra contains the identity operator?
3. If a $W^*$-algebra were open in the weak operator topology, what would happen? There would always be the identity operator?
4. If a $W^*$-algebra did not contain identity operator, what happens?
5. If a $W^*$-algebra were *closed* in the weak operator topology but it didn't contain identity operator, what happens ?
6. If a $W^*$-algebra were *open* in the weak operator topology but it didn't contain identity operator, what happens ?
7. If a $W^*$-algebra were *open* in the weak operator topology *and* contain identity operator, what happens ?

Comment: I think that, in the future, it would be better to split the question into several ones when they can be independently address. Also, some of the questions, like 4, are implications were the premise is false.

Comment: Regarding your question 3, a subalgebra of $B(H)$ is a linear space. If it is open, it will contain a neighborhood of $0$, thus, it would be all the space In other words, the only open subalgebra of $B(H)$ is $B(H)$ itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That's the nature of von Neumann algebras. They are the ones equal to they double commutants, which makes them closed in all the usual topologies (via von Neumann's Double Commutant Theorem).
2. There are several ways to see this. The identity is in the commutant of anything, so it is in particular in the double commutant. Or one can see that von Neumann algebras are generated by projections, that they have approximate units (all C$^*$-algebras do) and that that any approximate unit converges in the sot or wot topologies to the identity.
3. If any subspace $S$ of $B(H)$ contains a wot neighbourhood $N$ of  $0$, then for any $T\in B(H)$ there is $c>0$ with $cT\in N\subset S$. Then $T=\tfrac1c\,(cT)\in S$, so $S=B(H)$.
4. A von Neumann algebra $M$ always contains **its** identity. If that's not the identity of $B(H)$, it means that $M$ is *degenerate* (that is $\overline{MH}\subsetneq H$).
5. No answer. This never happens.
6. This never happens.
7. It equals $B(H)$. You don't need to assume that it contains the identity, that happens on its own.